# Wrapfigure pushed away by a small paragraph

Tags: wrapfigure

Please somebody explain me why this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{download.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}

foobar

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

does exactly what I want and produces [image: OK] while this (notice `{foobar}` instead of `foobar`) gives me this weirdness: [image: bad]

To be specific, I want to use `{\large foobar}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `\mbox{}` before like `\mbox{}{\large foobar}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{download.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}

\mbox{}{\large foobar}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works... I'm giving up on trying to figure LaTeX out.